# How to convert uint32_t to double or float and print?

Tags: c, embedded, stellaris

I'm using an analog to digital converter to read a voltage value from 0 to 3.3V. The ADC gives an output from `0x00` to `0x0FFF` (0 to 4095). I want to print the voltage reading with two decimal places. I have read a number of answers but nothing I've tried has worked. Here's my code:

```
uint32_t pui32ADC0Value[1]; // ADC0 data value
double D0v;                 // Decimal value

// Read value from ADC
ADCSequenceDataGet(ADC0_BASE, 3, pui32ADC0Value);

// Convert to decimal
D0v = (double)pui32ADC0Value[0] / 4095 * 3.3;

// Print to console
UART0printf("\n\r> D0 = %.2d V", D0v);
```

The output I get is: `D0 = ERROR2d V`

`pui32ADC0Value` prints without any problems and gives the expected values, so I know that it is working.

What does this error mean?

NOTE: `UART0printf` is a pre-defined UART function on the TIVA TM4C microcontroller I am using.

**UPDATE:** I wrongly assumed `UART0printf` is identical to `printf`, as I have used it before with `%u`, `%s`, and `%x`. However for numbers it only supports `%c`, `%i`, and `%u`. I am re-working my code and will update if I don't get anywhere.

**UPDATE 2:**
Could I do something like this? I know it will round incorrectly...

```
uint32_t pui32ADC0Value[1]; // ADC0 data value
uint32_t D0v[2];                 // Decimal value

// Read value from ADC
ADCSequenceDataGet(ADC0_BASE, 3, pui32ADC0Value);

// Convert to decimal
for ( int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
    D0v[i] = (pui32ADC0Value[0]/10^i) / 4096 * 3.3;
}

// Display the AIN0 (PE0) digital value on the console.
UART0printf("\n\r> D0 = %d.%d%d V", D0v[0],D0v[1],D0v[2]);
```

Comment: What is `UART0printf`? Are you sure it supports the same format-string syntax as C's `printf`?

Comment: why uint32_t pui32ADC0Value[1]; ? instead of uint32_t pui32ADC0Value; ??

Comment: @Nandu: I'm going to go on a limb and assume ADCSequenceDataGet takes a pointer to a `uint32_t`, so `uint32_t[1]` gets the free implicit conversion.  I don't think it was a good idea though.

Comment: This is from the ADC manufacturer. The call to ADCSequenceDataGet will only get one element for the array so I define it that way.

Comment: OK I lied, turns out UART0printf isn't identical to printf - it only supports %d %i and %u... meaning I've got a different question. I'll close this one out.

Comment: @LShaver Then it might be possible to use the real `printf` and redefine the `putchar` (might not be exactly this) to print via your UART interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this function works `printf` like:

```
UART0printf("\n\r> D0 = %.2f V\n", D0v);
```

Also your code may work a little faster if you use:

```
D0v = (double)pui32ADC0Value[0] * (3.3 / 4095);
```

The compiler will precompute `3.3 / 4095` and will do a single floating point multiply operation. Otherwise it's possible that the division is done first (which usually takes much more CPU cycles than a multiply) and then the multiply `* 3.3` will be done.

Also since you seems to need only 2 digit precision, you could use `float` (single precision) instead of `double`. It *may* execute faster (but it's possible to be even slower), this depends on the platform.

Update for **UPDATE2** in the question:

Try this:

```
uint32_t pui32ADC0Value[1]; // ADC0 data value
uint32_t D0v;               // Decimal value

// Read value from ADC
ADCSequenceDataGet(ADC0_BASE, 3, pui32ADC0Value);

// Convert to millivolts
D0v = pui32ADC0Value[0] * (3300.0 / 4095);

// Display the AIN0 (PE0) digital value on the console.
UART0printf("\n\r> D0 = %d mV", D0v); // If it's OK for you to display in mV
UART0printf("\n\r> D0 = %d.%03d V", D0v / 1000, D0v % 1000); // Print in V
```

Comment: @Dai Still a integer division have to be done then and on a specific platform I've seen that a single precision multiply (float) is faster than a integer division.

Comment: I don't think `float` is usually any faster than `double`, I'm pretty sure on most architectures they're computed identically.  The only difference is accuracy during storage.

Comment: @MooingDuck Right, this may depend on the actual platform. But on microcontrollers not having FPU (with float div implemented in SW), I think it will be faster.

Comment: I've got FPU, how would this affect it?

Comment: @LShaver It's good then and I can't say precisely which one is faster (`float` or `double`). You may be able to determine by using a timer to measure execution (or look in the CPU instruction set architecture for details regarding this). But if the operation is not so frequently done, maybe don't bother with it.

Comment: Quite simply, TI's UARTprintf() does not work with floats. It's not a full implementation of printf(). Break the float into two ints: integer part and fractional part. Then you can use UARTprintf() on the parts. Alternatively you COULD use sprinyf() but you may have to increase the stack size. I prefer to avoid using sprintf() on this platform for production code, but for a quick test program it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such `printf` format string as

```
%.2d
```

The formatter `%d` means *integer*, so there are no decimal-precision options for it. The `%.` is being parsed as an error (as it does not exist), and the `2d` is making it verbatim into your output.

[The formatter for floating-point values is `%f`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), so:

```
%.2f
```

*However, all this is based on the assumption that `UART0printf`, which you do not identify in your question whatsoever, is identical to `printf`.*